# Звук кнопки в Android

Tags: android, button, аудио

Всем привет, подскажите, как убрать в приложении звук нажатия кнопки. По нажатию происходит воспроизведение звука(определенной частоты), но каждое нажатие на кнопку добавляет свой(не нужный) звук.

Пробовал через :

```
audioManager =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

Но это отключает весь звук. Как именно прописать для кнопки?

Comment: Все же надо относящийся к делу код. Как и чем запускается звук, от этого можно и плясать. А можете сами разобраться, изучив 2 соответствующих набора методов для воспроизводства звуков.

Answer (score 2):

Отключение стандартного звука при клике программно:

```
button.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Или из xml:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
```